# How to backup entire gitlab.com account

Tags: gitlab, backup

Is there any way to backup a gitlab account (all repositories)?

I can't seem to find any documentation beyond the self-hosted versions.

Gitlab did have a catastrophic data data loss in 2017 that couldn't be recovered, and I'm worried about accidental or malicious deletion of data.

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe on gitlab.com you can export your repositories (projects) one at a time. That is, it's doable, but it might be time-consuming depending on the number of repositories you have. As you mention, on self-hosted versions it's possible to [backup a whole installation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#backup).

That said, there's an open issue to provide a batch export for projects on gitlab.com, based on the groups they're in:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13503

Regarding the database incident, a lot was learnt and a number of measures were taken to avoid it happening in the future, as per the [original report and post-mortem](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/02/01/gitlab-dot-com-database-incident/) .

Comment: Was quite the read, but nothing really surprising in there!  Bad luck for gitlab

Comment: Good find as well on the batch export issue.  Didn't think to google "batch export"

Comment: @MattPark: glad it helped. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if you think it did answer your question :)